# I have a British passport, can I travel by bus within the u.s with this?

Tags: passports, paperwork, uk-citizens, domestic-travel

I have a British passport, been living in the US for 10 months, have applied for my green card, can I travel within the US on my British passport?

Comment: If you have lived in the US for ten months, you are probably eligible for a driver's license or non-driver ID from your home state.  (In fact, it isprobably illegal for you to drive on a foreign license.)  You can use that, too, and you probably should if you have one.  In fact, in most cases, you don't even need an ID, though I haven't traveled by greyhound bus since 2001, so I don't know whether an ID requirement has been introduced.

Comment: By bus? You mean like a city bus? You just get on the bus and pay the fare. No one checks your ID.

Comment: @Calchas I suspect the question is about inter-city bus travel.

Answer (score 6):

In general, the only officials who care much about your immigration status in the US are immigration officials. If you travel by inter-city bus in the US, you're unlikely to encounter any immigration officials unless you're going through the southern parts of the states bordering Mexico. There, immigration sets up checkpoints on the road (I imagine they probably check passengers on buses, too).

As an English-speaking white non-US-citizen, whenever I encountered one of those checkpoints they simply asked what my citizenship was (they ask everybody that question), and waved me on without actually asking to see my passport. But if you have your passport with you and you're in the country legally, you won't have any problems even if they do ask to see your identification.

Comment: I believe immigration checks can also occur when traveling near the northern border.

Comment: @NateEldredge: That's quite possible. I never did encounter one there though. Similar advice would apply.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, according to this [TSA website](http://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification) your "**Foreign government-issued passport**" is about the only thing that will get you on a plane.  If you want to travel via car or bus, you don't even need your passport, although you might need it on a train.  The U.S. is the U.S. (i.e. it's one country with 50 united states, so feel free to look around, from *sea to shining sea*!)

Comment: Bus companies might require ID in some cases, for instance to pick up a ticket bought online.  E.g. [Greyhound](https://www.greyhound.com/en/help-and-info/ticket-info/payment-ticket-options) (expand the "online" section). I would guess a foreign passport would be accepted for this, but am not sure.  You don't need ID to ride in a car, but if you want to drive, you will need your foreign driver's license.

Comment: @NateEldridge in most states, new residents can only drive on their foreign licenses for a month or so.